# how can i add a id to my href link with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

So, i think it's really simple but i don't find a right solution

actually my links looking like this:

```
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 1</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 2</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 3</a>
```

How can i add automatically the same ID behind the Link?

Like this:

```
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh#ID">Link 1</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh#ID">Link 2</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh#ID">Link 3</a>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i m yet not the best at jquery - can you give me a short script what you mean? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by providing a function to `attr()`. The function will accept the current value of the attribute, and you can return the new value to use after appending the URL fragment, like this:

```js
$('a').attr('href', function(i, href) {
  return href + '#ID';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 1</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 2</a>
<a href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 3</a>
```

Note that you could also use `prop()` for this, but the important difference is that `prop()` will convert the value to an absolute URL, whereas `attr()` will retain the relative path.

Comment: 7 upvotes in 10 minutes?? Must be a popular question. Nice answer though

Comment: @Antonio no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $("a.link").attr("href", $("a.link").attr("href") + "#ID")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="link" href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="/kfhdsh/kfhdh">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: Note that this will set all `href` attributes to match the first one only.

Comment: Sorry to bother you , do you mean this only works for the first <a> tag ?

Comment: It will update all the `href` values, but will set them all to the same thing - the value of the first `href`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this is what the author want. Thank you .